# Edit table row php ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to edit this table row of an inline edit table. I am able to pass data from my js file to my PHP file for the query. The issue I am having is with getting the data from the table row. Every method I have tried to put table data in a JavaScript variable to send through ajax is not working. I have tried echoing the data, `json_encode`, using selectors...

I am new to this so maybe I am making a minor mistake. But I am able to Delete passing the id through an href. I need to edit several table cells and pass the df id:

```
$df_id = $row['df_id'];    
echo '<td class="border-left text-center" id="cg_crit">'.$row['ContentGrammarCritical'].'</td>';
echo '<td class="text-center">'.$row['ContentGrammarMajor'].'</td>';
echo '<td class="text-center">'.$row['ContentGrammarMinor'].'</td>';
echo '<td class="border-left text-center" >'.$row['functionalCritical'].'</td>';
echo '<td class="text-center">'.$row['functionalMajor'].'</td>';
echo '<td class="text-center">'.$row['functionalMinor'].'</td>';
echo '<td class="border-left text-center" >'.$row['NonfunctionalCritical'].'</td>';
echo '<td class="text-center">'.$row['NonfunctionalMajor'].'</td>';
echo '<td class="text-center">'.$row['NonfunctionalMinor'].'</td>';
```

Here is my code.

**The Edit Table**

```
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $df_id = $row['df_id'];
    $convert_day = $row['df_date'];
    $day_date = strftime("%A",strtotime($convert_day));
    echo '<tr><td>'.$day_date.'</td>';
    echo '<td id="pr_name">'.json_encode($row['pr_name']).'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$row['tcs_type'].'</td>';
    echo '<td class="text-center" id="rnd">'.$row['df_round'].'</td>';
    echo '<td class="border-left text-center" id="cg_crit">'.$row['ContentGrammarCritical'].'</td>';
    echo '<td class="text-center">'.$row['ContentGrammarMajor'].'</td>';
    echo '<td class="text-center">'.$row['ContentGrammarMinor'].'</td>';
    echo '<td class="border-left text-center" >'.$row['functionalCritical'].'</td>';
    echo '<td class="text-center">'.$row['functionalMajor'].'</td>';
    echo '<td class="text-center">'.$row['functionalMinor'].'</td>';
    echo '<td class="border-left text-center" >'.$row['NonfunctionalCritical'].'</td>';
    echo '<td class="text-center">'.$row['NonfunctionalMajor'].'</td>';
    echo '<td class="text-center">'.$row['NonfunctionalMinor'].'</td>';
    echo '<td  class="border-left" contenteditable="false"><div class="ticket-actions col-md-2">
    <div class="btn-group dropdown">
        <a type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle btn-sm" data-toggle="dropdown">
        Manage
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <a class="dropdown-item editbtn">
            <i class="fa fa-reply fa-fw"></i>Edit</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item cancelbtn" href="javascript:history.go(0)">
            <i class="fa fa-reply fa-fw"></i>Cancel</a>
            <button class="dropdown-item savebtn" id="">
            <i class="fa fa-check text-success fa-fw"></i>Save</button>
        <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>

        <a class="dropdown-item" href="DB/defect/delete_defect.php?id='. $df_id .'">
            <i class="fa fa-times text-danger fa-fw"></i>Delete</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div></td></tr>';
}
```

**THE AJAX**

```
$('.savebtn').click(function() {
    $.each(currentTD, function() {
        //alert("second if "+currentTD.html());
        $(this).prop('contenteditable', false).removeAttr("style");
        //var df_id = $(this).('#pr_name');
        var df_id2 = 
        var df_id3 = "45";
        console.log(df_id2);
        $.post("DB/defect/edit_defect.php", {
            df_id: df_id2,
            day_date: df_id3
        }, function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        });

        $('.editbtn').show();
        $('.savebtn').hide();
        $('.cancelbtn').hide();
    });
})
```

Comment: This is me trying to test the code var df_id2 = 
                  var df_id3 = "45" ;
                  console.log(df_id2);
                  $.post("DB/defect/edit_defect.php", {df_id: df_id2, day_date: df_id3}

Comment: I think your code is incomplete `var df_id2 = `

Comment: Yes, i was trying different methods to get the data but nothing i tried work so I just delete it.